# why `Private Sub` instead of `Public Sub`

Tags: vb.net, module

I have searched for the difference between `Private Sub`, `Public Sub` and `Sub` to make sure of what i have to use.

i have got a question, why don't we use `Public Sub` instead of `Private Sub`?
`Public Sub` can be accessed from any module while `Private Sub` is only limited to this small place

File 1:

```
Module ModuleA
    Public Sub Test()
        messagebox.show("Message from Public Sub")
    End Sub
End Module
```

File 2:

```
Module ModuleB
    Private Sub Run_Public_Sub Handles Button.Click
        Test()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: If you have a button click event (Sub) it is meant to perform whatever you want to happen when the button is clicked.  As such it doesnt need to be public because it ought not be invoked other than as the result of a button click.  Likewise, if I have a class to manage something, it doesnt benefit from hemp from the outside.  That file 2 code is not legal by the way - a module cant have a button or an event handler

Comment: IMO that kind of question should always be put in reverse order. Why should X be more visible than it is currently ? And it needs a reason good answer to that question to effectively make it more visible.

Comment: @Plutonix I think it was just supposed to be for an example to show `Private Sub` vs `Public Sub`; even though I agree that a better example could have been presented. Also, a module can have a function like `Public Function Create_Button(ByVal buttonText As String) As System.Windows.Forms.Button` that returns a button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deciding whether to use `Private` over `Public` all comes down to the intended scope of what is being declared. While yes, using `Public` with a `Sub` means that the code can be referenced from most anywhere and may seem like a good idea, doing so may cause undesirable results.

For example, if I created all of my `Sub`s as `Public`, I may inadvertently call a `Sub` that relies on something that isn't there which will result in a `NullReferenceException` at runtime. See the following example:

```
Class fooBar
    Private Property myPrivateProperty As String
    Public Property myPublicProperty As String
    Public Property myValue As String

    Public Sub New()
        myPublicProperty = "Hello"
    End Sub

    Public Sub callThisSubFirst()
        myPrivateProperty = "World"
        setValue()
    End Sub

    Public Sub setValue()
        myValue = myPublicProperty.ToUpper & myPrivateProperty.ToUpper
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see in the above example, I have used the `Public` modifier on all `Sub`s in the class `fooBar`. If I were to call the `setValue()` method before calling the `callThisSubFirst()` method, a `NullReferenceException` will occur because I am trying to call the `.ToUpper` string extension on a string object that is not instantiated.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim test As New fooBar
    test.setValue() ' NRE will occur here
    Console.WriteLine(test.myValue)
End Sub
```

What should have happened was that the `callThisSubFirst()` method should have been called in order to instantiate `myPrivateProperty` and only after that should have the `setValue()` method have been called. If I had marked the `setValue()` method as `Private` then I would have received an error stating that `setValue()` was not available in the context when I attempted to call it outside of the class; which is exactly what needs to happen since `setValue()` depends on the `callThisSubFirst()` method being executed. Here's how the code should have been written:

```
Class fooBar
    Private Property myPrivateProperty As String
    Public Property myPublicProperty As String
    Public Property myValue As String

    Public Sub New()
        myPublicProperty = "Hello"
    End Sub

    Public Sub callThisSubFirst()
        myPrivateProperty = "World"
        setValue()
    End Sub

    Private Sub setValue()
        myValue = myPublicProperty.ToUpper & myPrivateProperty.ToUpper
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here's how it should have been used:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim test As New fooBar
        test.callThisSubFirst() ' Hurray, no exceptions!
        Console.WriteLine(test.myValue)
End Sub
```

That's just one example of how marking everything to `Public` can cause issues in your application. There are multitudes of other reasons why doing so is also a less than ideal solution, the biggest being maintainability. If everything is marked as `Public` in a class and a small change needs to be made to a single method, the entire code base will need to be checked to confirm that the change doesn't affect any other callers which may be expecting the original behavior. If the method or function is marked as `Private` to begin with, then the only code that needs to be checked is the code that resides within the same scope.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to understand the difference between *public* and *private*, that a good start. Yes, you could use *public* wherever *private* can be used but that's not necessarily a good thing. I believe the main reason for using both access levels is maintainability. Changes to code that is accessible from outside of the class or module can cause additional changes to the other classes and components. This can complicate code modifications by causing multiple changes throughout an application. Changes to a private routine can only directly affect the class or module that contains it. Making routines private prevents other developers from using them directly. This frees the developer of the class to make changes to private code without having to be concerned that it might adversely affect other developers.